# how does a gpiochipNN is selected or set in gpiolib kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, device-tree, gpio

I am looking into kernel gpiolib and gpio-xilinx.c. I see that my device has only

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
gpiochip0: GPIOs 960-1023,
```

I am confused on how this 960 has arrived. How does the kernel knows it has to set this number 960? I can't see this number 960 in the device tree. From where this 960 number comes from?

```
 /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip960
```

I am expecting to set -

```
gpio237
gpiochip192
gpiochip224
```

Answer (score 0):

The gpiochip base is set to -1 in  gpio-xilinx.c. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.5/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-xilinx.c#L319

This means that gpiochip_find_base will be called:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.5/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c#L181

This tries to find the first available range from ARCH_NR_GPIOS.

I'm pretty sure you have ARCH_NR_GPIOS == 1024 and ngpios == 64. This leads to a range from 960 to 1023.